# Hosting website on VPS, Configure TURN server

Tags: node.js, webrtc, stun, turn

I have developed a web based **video calling** application. I'm planning to host it on **GoDaddy Linux VPS**. But the tech support is not sure if i could configure a **TURN**, **STUN** server on the same VPS. Is it possible to do so? Or should I go for separate commercial TURN service provider?

Can anybody help me out? Anybody who has done it? Its my first time hosting a website.
My website is all ready I just have to host it. Its based on Node js platform.

Comment: This question does not belong on SO, it is off topic. You'll find better help on https://serverfault.com/ where server administration experts hang out.

Comment: I'm sorry. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: You can host TURN, STUN server on same VPS. Provided VPS should have enough resources.

Comment: @Harikrishnan Thank you. By any chance have you heard of http://numb.viagenie.ca/ . Is it a free TURN server?